# Java ArrayList into Name value pair

Tags: java, arraylist

In a java class, am using an  arraylist say reports containing  list of all the reports which have reportid, reportname, reporttype etc which i want to add into NameValuePair and send a Http postmethod call to a particular url.

I want to add the arraylists - reportname  into name value pair(org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair) and then use the http client post method to submit the name value pair data to a particular url.

Here is my name value pair

```
if (validateRequest()) {
        NameValuePair[] data = {
            new NameValuePair("first_name", firstName),
            new NameValuePair("last_name", lastName),
            new NameValuePair("email", mvrUser.getEmail()),
            new NameValuePair("organization", mvrUser.getOrganization()),
            new NameValuePair("phone", mvrUser.getPhone()),
            new NameValuePair("website", mvrUser.getWebsite()),
            new NameValuePair("city", mvrUser.getCity()),
            new NameValuePair("state", mvrUser.getState()),
            new NameValuePair("country", mvrUser.getCountry()),
            new NameValuePair(**"report(s)", reports**.)
        };
```

please suggest me how to add the reports arraylist reportname into reports field of NameValuePair.

--
thanks

@ adarsh
can I use with generics something like this?

```
reportname = "";
for (GSReport report : reports) {
        reportname = reportname + report.getReportName();
        reportname += ",";
    }
```

and then add in namevalue pair as

```
new NameValuePair("report(s)", reportname)
```

Comment: Of course you can but I only used the indexed for loop to remove the trailing `|` delimiter. I showed you string concatenation approach for simplicity. I strongly recommend you change to `StringBuilder` if you have many items in the list.

Comment: For forming a delimited string list from an arraylist, just use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(Collection, char).. From the apache common lang project. Also, make sure you choose a delimiter that is not being used in any of the strings in the reports list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot do that. `NameValuePair` takes in `String` arguments in the constructor. It makes sense as it is used for HTTP POST.

What you can do is come up with a way to serialize the `Report` object into String and send this string as a string parameter. One way of doing this maybe is to delimit the parameters of the `Report` class.

`reports=reportName1|reportName2|reportName3`

Assuming `reports` is your `ArrayList`,

```
String reportsStr = "";

for(int i = 0; i < reports.size(); i++) {
    reportStr += reportName;
    if(i != reports.size() - 1) {
        reportsStr += "|";
    }
}

NameValuePair nvPair = new NameValuePair("reports", reportsStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

for name value pair use map like things... eg. Hastable(it is synchronized) , u can use other
implementation of Map which are not synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to serialize your reports `ArrayList` into a JSON formatted `String`.

```
new NameValuePair("reports", reportsAsJson)
```

You can build your reportsAsJson variable using any of the JSON serialization libraries (like the one at http://json.org/java/). It will have approximatively this format :

```
reportsAsJson = "[{reportid:'1',reportname:'First Report',reporttype:'Type 1'}, {reportid:'2',reportname:'Seond Report',reporttype:'Type 2'}]";
```